# Getting a 404 on CXF GET,PUT & DELETE resource while POST works fine

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I have following service..

```
@Path("/persistence")
public interface Persistence {

  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Path("/projects/{pid}/items")
  public Response getItems(@PathParam("pid") String projectId);

  @POST
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Consumes("application/json")
  @Path("/items")
  public Response addItems(String payload);

  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Path("/items/{itemId}")
  public Response getItem(@PathParam("itemId") String itemId);

  @PUT
  @Consumes("application/json")
  @Path("/items/{itemId}")
  public Response updateItem(@PathParam("itemId") String itemId,String payload);

  @DELETE
  @Consumes("application/json")
  @Path("/items/{itemId}")
  public Response deleteItem(@PathParam("itemId") String itemId);

}
```

I deploy this service on tomcat and everything is fine. Service gets deployed without any errors. After that when i try to test it only POST works and every other resource results in a 404 not found error. I am using REST Console to test the service. Also when i do

```
http://localhost:8081/serv?_wadl
```

I only see the POST endpoint listed and none of the GET, PUT or DELETE resources show in the list. What am i missing?

Comment: From what I see, everything is fine. Can you show the URLs of your GET/PUT/DELETE tests?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8081/serv/persistence/items/6a46f095-1506-442e-83c9-183c9e3379fe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This service is declared as an `interface`.

**Where is the class implementing this interface?**

There are some rules about "annotation inheritance" when using JAX-RS.

JAX-RS 1.1 - 3.6 Annotation Inheritance:

> JAX-RS annotations MAY be used on the methods and method parameters of
>   a super-class or an implemented interface. Such annotations are
>   inherited by a corresponding sub-class or implementation class method
>   provided that method and its parameters do not have any JAX-RS
>   annotations of its own. Annotations on a super-class take precedence
>   over those on an implemented interface. If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on
>   the super class or interface method are ignored.

Comment: gotcha.. i had redundant @PathParam annotations in the implementation class. solved. :)

Comment: Sometimes people mess with the config files (like web.xml). They reassign the web service path, then nothing works right. I am glad this was not your case (I hate to be downvoted).